# Attempting to gather descriptive statistics on some data using sapply() and running into some issues

Tags: r, syntax, logic

I'm currently attempting to take my data, which is a 3 variable table defined by data, and find the mean, median, standard deviation, 20th percentile, and 70th percentile using the following code:

```
sapply(data,mean,median,sd,quantile(probs=c(0.2,0.7)))
```

However when I use this I get an error stating the following:

```
Error in if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)] : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? It's the last few bits of my assignment and this is the current block I've ran into

Comment: You can only apply one function at a time.

Comment: As @RuiBarradas mentioned, it needs a lamdba expression i.e. `sapply(data, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), median = median(x)))`